# Workaround to "allowThrowsTagsForSubclasses" issue in Eclipse Checkstyle Plug-in

Tags: java, eclipse, checkstyle

In my javadoc comments, I often put `@throws` comments for subclasses of exceptions, like:

```
/**
 * My method.
 * @throws SubclassOfMyException when something specific happens
 * @throws MyException if any other error occurs
 */
public void myMethod() throws MyException {
    // ...
}
```

Checkstyle is supposed to handle this format by setting `allowThrowsTagsForSubclasses` in Javadoc Method module. However, Eclipse Checkstyle Plug-in is frequently (but not always) tagging such cases as errors. Running checkstyle from the command line does not tag these as errors. I'm using version 5.6.0.201209221626 of the plug in.

Any suggestion for a workaround? Perhaps I could change my documentation style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me add a few notes. Setting [RedundantThrows](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_coding.html#RedundantThrows) to allow subclasses is okay in my book. I would even allow runtime exceptions to be declared as well:

```xml
<module name="RedundantThrows">
  <property name="allowUnchecked" value="true"/>
  <property name="allowSubclasses" value="true"/>
</module>
```

Either way, you should be able to satisfy your original scenario by configuring the [JavadocMethod](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_javadoc.html#JavadocMethod) check. Make sure that `allowUndeclaredRTE` (which allows runtime exceptions to be present in Javadoc `@throws` tags without being declared in the method signature) and `allowThrowsTagsForSubclasses` are set to `true` (you already mentioned the latter).

In addition to those, there is `logLoadErrors`, which may lead to a Checkstyle warning like *"Unable to get class information"* if the exception in question cannot be loaded. You may want to turn that off if you cannot resolve the classpath problem (a workaround that I would not recommend, but it exists). Example:

```xml
<module name="JavadocMethod">
    <property name="allowUndeclaredRTE" value="true"/>
    <property name="allowThrowsTagsForSubclasses" value="true"/>
    <property name="logLoadErrors" value="false"/>
</module>
```

The Eclipse Checkstyle plugin as such is quite reliable, and although I've been using it for many years it has never exhibited any serious faults (missing features are a different story). So the above configuration really should work.

If you are still having problems after that, then it has nothing directly to do with Checkstyle, but instead with Eclipse or your use of it (like how your classpaths are built, if you have custom builders, if you let non-Eclipse programs write to the workspace and so forth; out of scope for this question).

Answer (score 0):

You could allow subclass throws in Checkstyle:

```
    <module name="RedundantThrows">
      <property name="allowSubclasses" value="true"/>
    </module>
```

and change your method signature to:

```
public void myMethod() throws SubclassOfMyException, MyException {
```

Some may consider it bad code style, though.